# Why do some fast travel markers shine?

Tags: destiny-2

I opened up the navigation menu to travel to the Tower to collect some weekly rewards, and as I in the middle warping, I re-opened the navigation to see if there were any Public Events happening on Earth. When the map loaded, something caught my attention.

[image]

To the bottom left, there is a fast travel marker that is shining. I asked a few friends on Destiny 2, but they didn't know and I couldn't find any references online either.

At first, I had assumed it was indicating there was a Public Event occurring in the area, but that not the case as there was going on to the north. I checked a few seconds later and the shining marker became a regular marker like the rest.

Why do some fast travel markers shine like this?

Comment: I have noticed this happening seemingly randomly but mainly it's if you select a location, such as a mission or public event, as a waypoint. The closest fast travel to it will light up then.

Comment: @Virusbomb That might be possible, but I'm not sure if that is entirely the case. I noted that was in transits to the tower when I saw this, so I wasn't tracking any public events or missions

Comment: I've also had that happen, my only guess on what it could be is something like tracking an event that has ended but the fast travel stays highlighted or maybe it's just a weird bug. I'm sure about how it's suppose to work but don't know why it happens like this.

Comment: I tried google, but there isn't much information on this game.

Comment: @Virusbomb after some testing, you are correct. I selected different missions and the closest fast travel marker started to shine; it showing up while in the middle of a warp must’ve been a glitch in the matrix . If you want to post it as an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fast travel locations will shine when you select a destination, such as a public event, adventure, or quest, and the closest fast travel to that location will light up showing which one to choose.

Occasionally during warps between planets/tower some fast travel locations will light up anyway without a highlighted destination. This is most likely a simple bug with an unknown exact cause.